# creating shortcode to pull json array

Tags: functions, shortcode, api, json

Frankly - this may be a duplicate of another question I have out there. Sorry if it is. I'm learning this site and PHP/Wordpress development. I have partnerships with local sites that use JSON and we're working together. They aren't Wordpress specialists though.

I want to pull what my friend calls a JSON object from this url:

http://aggrenda.com/mpellas/michael-pellas/events.json

I'm trying to create a shortcode that can parse the data into scheduled posts. I have specific date, address, description (and other) data.

I've been working with my PHP at phpfiddle.org and have been successful. I haven't been able to translate anything to Wordpress functionality though.

Here's one of my latest attempts:

```
add_shortcode('aggrenda', 'requestAggrendaEvents');
function requestAggrendaEvents() 
{
$json = file_get_contents("http://aggrenda.com/mpellas/michael-pellas/events.json");
$data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($data['events'][1]['title']);
}
```

The basic php works, but if I chnge file_get_contents with wp_remote_get I end up with nothing but a blank page...or a null return depending on little variations in my code. I put everything into functions.php.

I have anumber of other snippets where the PHP works but i can't translate it to WP functionality. I'm sure i'm mssing something small. Help?

Comment: Could you add an example _with_ `wp_remote_get()` used? It would be easier to look/copy it than try to guess what goes wrong. :)

Comment: This returns only "null" - add_shortcode('aggrenda', 'requestAggrendaEvents');
function requestAggrendaEvents() 
 {
 $json = wp_remote_get("http://aggrenda.com/mpellas/michael-pellas/events.json");
 $data = json_decode($json, true);
 var_dump($data['events'][1]['title']);
 }

Comment: @mpellas, you missed `http` in above example, did you missed just over here or you tried with this invalid url only? Second thing, can you check if cURL is enabled on your server?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That was an error in my copy and paste. I just tried the code and made sure I had the http in front of the URL and only got NULL back. I can check on if cURL is enabled on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [documentation on `wp_remote_get()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) it doesn't return you just the body of requested resource. Its return will be either the array of data or `WP_Error` object on failure.

The simplest snippet to get to the body would be:

```
$json = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $url ) );
```

PS it's kinda weird to be doing this in shortocde, are you sure it's most appropriate place for it? :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For my current skillset, I wasn't sure if add_shortcode or wp_insert_post would be more appropriate. I found wp_remote_retrieve_body today but haven't used it. Would you not use that in a shortcode?

Comment: I think I will let you build it out some more rather than dump bunch of stuff on your head. :) Processing of stuff doesn't _have_ to be in the post content / shortcode and probably shouldn't, but if that's fastest for you to make sense of it for starters then just do that.

Comment: I appreciate that! I'm really trying to get through this with one project that I'm building for a specific purpose. I'm getting the hand of PHP...but it's driving me crazy that I can't translate it over to Wordpress. It'll come in time :)

Comment: If i could throw this out there...This is my current attempt: add_shortcode('aggrenda', 'requestAggrendaEvents');
function requestAggrendaEvents() 
{
$url      = 'http://aggrenda.com/mpellas/michael-pellas/events.json';
$response = wp_remote_get( esc_url_raw( $url ) );

/* Will result in $api_response being an array of data,
parsed from the JSON response of the API listed above */
$api_response = json_decode( wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response ), true );

}